# the meaning of "rather than not at all"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*I'm glad that Paul Torday took up writing in his 60s (**rather than not at all***).

Can you tell me what is meant by the phrase "rather than not at all". The literal meaning does not make any sense and the possible idiomatic one I am not able to find on the internet.

Comment: *better late than never*.

Comment: Think of "rather than" as meaning "instead of".  I'm glad that Paul Torday took up writing in his 60s, instead of not taking it up at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can understand this phrase, *rather than not at all*, literally, in the context, like this:

> ***rather than*** = instead of
>   ***not at all*** = not taking up writing (in other words, never start writing)